# How to extend file in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, yaml

I have a YAML file ('config.yaml') with this content:

```
egress:
  hostName: example.com
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
```

How can I extend this file in groovy?

Result must be like this:

```
egress:
  hostName: example.com
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
tag: 1.1.1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you want to treat `config.yaml` just as an ordinary text file, then you can just use common Groovy ways to work with IO:

```
String path = 'path/to/file'
File cfgFile = new File(path, 'config.yml')
cfgFile.withWriterAppend() { writer ->
    writer.writeLine('\ntag: 1.1.1')
}
```

or just

```
new File(path, 'config.yml') << '\ntag: 1.1.1'
```

But if you want to build something more sophisticated and aware of YAML format of this file, then you can use SnakeYaml library:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.25')
])
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

String path = '../data/'
File cfgFile = new File(path, 'config.yaml')

Yaml yaml = new Yaml()
Map content = [:]
cfgFile.withReader { reader ->
    content = yaml.load(reader)
}

content.put('tag', '1.1.1')

cfgFile.withWriter { writer ->
    yaml.dump(content, writer)
}
```

If you use Groovy 3.0+ then you can use built-in `YamlSlurper` and `YamlBuilder` instead.
(Groovy 3.0 is not released yet at the time of writing this answer)

One disadvantage here is that parsing and re-writing yaml file will get rid of comments and will reformat entire file.